# Publishing news reads activity using the JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am publishing activity to Facebook using the JavaScript SDK , but I am getting the response as "undefined"

```
<script>

setTimeout(function(){ 
    FB.api(
    '/me/news.reads' , 
    { article : document.location.href }, 
    function(response) {
        alert(response.name);
    });  
},10000);  

</script>
```

What should I do in my approach to correct this?

Answer (score -2):

Run the below and check the response

```
<script>

setTimeout(function(){ 
    FB.api(
    '/me/news.reads' , 
    { article : document.location.href }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });  
},10000);  

</script>
```